# How To Track the Real IP Address Behind the Proxy

Tags: php

How can we track the Real IP address behind the proxy using PHP?I mean a pure PHP implementation.Because they can turn off the js of their browsers.BTW when the JS is turn on I may use HTML 5 geolocation so I don't need the IP address to locate the user.

Answer (score 12):

You can look at the [X-Forwarded-For](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) HTTP header if one is sent, but there is no guaranteed way to know.

Comment: And to make it absolutely clear: **THIS HEADER CANNOT BE TRUSTED** unless **ALL** requests go through a proxy **YOU** control and no request can reach your server directly without either going through the proxy or that header being stripped somehow. There are so many PHP apps out there which simply use the IP from that header unconditionally if it's available...

Answer (score 10):

This PHP code will work, and is useful for forward and reverse proxies. For reverse proxies, note that the X_FORWARDED_FOR header information, if available at all, can be forged and should not be trusted at all.

```
if($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"] != ""){
   $IP = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
   $proxy = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
   $host = @gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]);
}else{
   $IP = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
   $proxy = "No proxy detected";
   $host = @gethostbyaddr($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
}
```

Comment: it's because of variable name. $IP should be named `$an_HTTP_header_that_may_looks_like_an_IP_address_possibly_faked`

Comment: Lol you are funny, Colonel :) I already stated the Caveat in my explanation. Either way, it remains the received IP by the way: forged or not! I love your sense of humor though.

Comment: @Cogicero: Please consider updating this answer to use the `$_SERVER` array instead of `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS`. The latter is outdated and disabled by default in recent PHP versions.

Comment: Spot on, ThiefMaster. Now fixed. Thanks for looking out.

Answer (score 1):

The user who is behind a proxy does not have a globally routable IP address. If you want to maintain session state, you're better off having a session key you generate, and setting it as a cookie, or keeping it in the URL (there are tradeoffs with that approach).

If you really want to find out what their IP address is on their own network, you could probably use javascript in the page to find it out, and then send it back to your server.