# Track IP address behind proxy Hotmail

Tags: php, proxy, hotmail

I'm trying to use an image to fire a PHP script to record IP address of the email recipient.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349604/how-to-track-the-real-ip-address-behind-the-proxy)  but no proxy is detected.

How do I overcome this challenge by Hotmail?

Comment: If you are trying to obtain the IP address of the reader of the email this should not work. As I understand the Hotmail servers fetch the image back end and then present it to the user if it's safe. The user in no way should be loading remote images.

Comment: Now that's interesting, thanks for sharing! Can you make this an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I wonder why I got a vote down here though, how did I deserve it?

Comment: It's probably frowned upon to try to get a user IP from an email, but this is a valid question. So consider it up voted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to obtain the IP address of the reader of the email this should not work. As I understand the Hotmail servers fetch the image back end and then present it to the user if it's safe. The user in no way should be loading remote images.

Note the URI of the image in the email, for example:

```
https://blu002.mail.live.com/Handlers/ImageProxy.mvc?bicild=&canary=QS3sf5XTfvb0EhoYPqKqj%sdgsdgg%2bk7%2fUeHzTVkYo31k%3d0&url=http%3a%2f%2fo2.mypubliceye.com%2fextranet%2fclient%2f35%2fimages%2fo2-masthead.jpg
```

If the email reader is using a client for Hotmail, like from a phone or Thunderbird then this may be an option. But is probably frowned upon for obvious reasons.