# How to get client's IP? php default functions are not working like getenv,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php, ip

I am getting my local IP with this code

```
if (getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')) 

    $ip=getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
else

    $ip=getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
```

I am getting clients default gateway IP but I want client's live IP.

Comment: it is not possible to obtain the IP address behind a gateway if the gateway is using NAT. That's networking basics.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5349604/how-to-track-the-real-ip-address-behind-the-proxy

Comment: There is only one tool: [JS-Recon](http://www.andlabs.org/tools/jsrecon.html) that based on HTML5

Comment: possible duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/5349604/… – bansi

-- I have already tried that but it is not working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First comment is right but with some proxy client's IP is available in HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR, it seems not to be your case.

Watch other environment variables (phpinfo() or print_r($_SERVER)) to see if your client IP is available.

If not, this is not possible. The proxy is hidding the real IP (as it should be).

Answer (score 1):

PHPs [`getenv(`REMOTE_ADDR`)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) [will give you the visible network address of the client](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3875.html):

```
 REMOTE_ADDR  = hostnumber
 hostnumber   = ipv4-address | ipv6-address
 ipv4-address = 1*3digit "." 1*3digit "." 1*3digit "." 1*3digit
 ipv6-address = hexpart [ ":" ipv4-address ]
 hexpart      = hexseq | ( [ hexseq ] "::" [ hexseq ] )
 hexseq       = 1*4hex *( ":" 1*4hex )
```

However, as indicated, your server can only obtain IP addresses it actually can see. If the client is hiding behind a gateway (p.e. with a NAT), then you'll only see the NAT address. PHPs [`getenv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) can't change those fundamental network basics.

Comment: I have already used  getenv(REMOTE_ADDR) but cannot get currant IP of client.

Comment: I can only repeat myself. your server can only obtain IP addresses it actually can see. If the client is hiding behind a gateway (p.e. with a NAT), then you'll only see the NAT address.